# Verifying a delegate was called with Moq

Tags: c#, unit-testing, delegates, moq

i got a class that gets by argument a delegate.
This class invokes that delegate, and i want to unit test it with Moq.
how do i verify that this method was called ?

example class :

```
public delegate void Foo(int number);

public class A
{
   int a = 5;

   public A(Foo myFoo)
   {
      myFoo(a);
   }
}
```

and I want to check that Foo was called.
Thank you.

Comment: I think that you need to change the answer accepted, because the @Lukazoid 's answer is more right than your choice.

Comment: In the constructor, should the line read `myFoo(a)`? You are invoking that instance of `Foo`, not the `Foo` class itself, right?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

What about using an anonymous function? It can act like an inline mock here, you don't need a mocking framework.

```
bool isDelegateCalled = false;
var a = new A(a => { isDelegateCalled = true});

//do something
Assert.True(isDelegateCalled);
```

Comment: Nice, but... The question **specifically** asks about Moq.

Comment: @rsenna If you read the answer below, you will see that it wasn't supported in Moq when I posted my answer. I provided a solution for the verification OP was trying to do.

Comment: The OP probably also found that adequate, which is, again, nice. But it doesn't change the fact that it does not solve **my** problem - which could be described by the very same title in this question here. :-)

Comment: Somehow this thread made me laugh :D I hope you guys are having fun writing code as well :D

Answer (score 73):

As of [this commit](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/commit/e614ae5b4a14896503b59e2a70ac799bb66e741b) Moq now supports the mocking of delegates, for your situation you would do it like so:

```
var fooMock = new Mock<Foo>();
var a = new A(fooMock.Object);
```

Then you can verify the delegate was invoked:

```
fooMock.Verify(f => f(5), Times.Once);
```

Or:

```
fooMock.Verify(f => f(It.IsAny<int>()), Times.Once);
```

Answer (score 4):

Moq does not support mocking delegates. But you can create some interface, with method, which matches your delegate signature:

```
public interface IBar
{
    void M(int number);
}
```

Then create mock, which implements this interface, and use this mock object to create delegate:

```
Mock<IBar> bar = new Mock<IBar>();
Foo foo = new Foo(bar.Object.M); 
A a = new A(foo);
bar.Verify(x => x.M(5));
```

After exercising your sut, you will be able to verify expectations on your mocked object.

UPDATE: Actually you can simply pass `bar.Object.M` to your sut, without `Foo` delegate instance creation. But anyway, mocking delegates requires interface creation.

Comment: Just an FYI, Moq now supports the mocking of delegates see my answer and [here](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/commit/e614ae5b4a14896503b59e2a70ac799bb66e741b)

Answer (score 4):

You can do something like that:

```
 public interface IWithFOOMethod
 {
     void FooAlikeMethod(int number);
 }

 Mock<IWithFOOMethod> myMock = new Mock<IWithFOOMethod>();

 A a = new A(myMock.Object.FooAlikeMethod);

 myMock.Verify(call => call.Foo(It.IsAny<int>()), Times.Once())
```

Answer (score 1):

Since Moq doesn't support mocking delegates, I'll usually handle this with something like:

```
var list = new List<int> ();
var del = i => list.Add (i);
var a = new A(del);
list.ShouldContainOnly (new[] { 5 });
```

where the delegate provided performs some simple, verifiable action.

Comment: Just an FYI, Moq now supports the mocking of delegates see my answer and [here](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/commit/e614ae5b4a14896503b59e2a70ac799bb66e741b)